# Retrofit GET for instagram access token. Getting 4xx but what am I missing?

Tags: android, instagram, retrofit

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Im on the last step (three). Im making a GET request and Im getting a response but it is now successful, im getting code 400 saying im missing client_id but I am not missing it. I saw a few others with the same problem but no clear solution. Below is the relevant code please have a look im a little bit new to retrofit.

```
    //here I am creating the request to send through retrofit...
    <!-- language: java -->
    TokenRequest request = new TokenRequest();
    request.setClient_id(Constants.CLIENT_ID);
    request.setClient_secret(Constants.CLIENT_SECRET);
    request.setGrant_type(Constants.AUTORISATION_CODE);
    request.setRedirect_uri(Constants.REDIRECT_URI);
    request.setCode(code);
```

//this is the actual request

```
        final Call<TokenResponse> accessToken =  ServiceManager.createTokenService().getAccessToken(request);
        accessToken.enqueue(new Callback<TokenResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TokenResponse> call, Response<TokenResponse> response) {

                mtext.setText("hello");

                if(response.isSuccess()){
                    mtext.setText("success");
                }else{
                    try {
                        mtext.setText(response.errorBody().string());
                        //Log.d("mylog", response.errorBody().string());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
```

At the moment its not going into the if block but showing the error in the else block.

Comment: Can you make sure that the ClientID is correct? You can regenerate it if possible.

Comment: I have made sure the client id is correct, also sorry for the mistake in the title but in the implementation it is infact a POST and not a get. That is not the problem.

Comment: Why are you manually creating request? You are totally misusing retrofit. You better look into okHttp library.

Comment: retrofit is used to make your work with REST API easier, not http methods and requests

Comment: Hey Mussa! Im pretty new to retrofit so ill look into it. However are there any immediate problems with the request that I have made? I will also try it with the okHttp just now

Comment: The reason why i couldnt use the okhttp way is because I was having a hard time constructing the URL. I have all the pieces required but I wasnt sure how to concatenate them because on the instagram page they show a weird curl way of making the request

Comment: @HasanNagaria try it with **okHttp** and you shouldn't have problems. As for **retrofit** you better do a couple of tuts and examples to grab the idea.

Comment: @HasanNagaria can you post your retrofit configuration and api interface code. Also http error message.

Comment: Alright breaking news xD I Was finally able to make it work. Im getting the response and everything it turns out I have a problem in my interface. So now my question is can you tell me why my first interface was wrong and my second one correct? Ill post the wrong one first and then the correct one. Considering this was the problem you wont need the rest of the code.

Comment: @POST("/oauth/access_token")
      Call<TokenResponse> getAccessToken(@Body TokenRequest tokenRequest); //so this returns a token response and we need to build a pojo for that.

Comment: @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/oauth/access_token")
    Call<TokenResponse> getAccessToken(@Field("client_id") String client_id, @Field("client_secret") String client_secret,
                                       @Field("redirect_uri") String redirect_uri, @Field("grant_type") String grant_type,
                                       @Field("code") String code);

Comment: Instead of passing the entire token request object as the body i sent them as individual @fields. What exactly does fields do? Why couldnt I do it using the first way.

Comment: Thats the whole idea of retrofit, so you don't have to build your request manually. You just call a method in your api service with appropriate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I had my API interface built incorrectly, you can check the comments for the incorrect one. The correct one is the one below:

```
@FormUrlEncoded @POST("/oauth/access_token") 
Call<TokenResponse> getAccessToken(@Field("client_id") String client_id,
         @Field("client_secret") String client_secret,  
         @Field("redirect_uri") String redirect_uri, 
         @Field("grant_type") String grant_type, @Field("code") String code);
```

This was really tricky for me being new to retrofit hope it helps if you're stuck at the same problem!